# How to log all Odoo 13 RPC request and response

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo-13

I'm using Odoo 13 and I need to log all the data of XMLRPC requests and responses. Could anyone help me?

I've tried to add this line to the config file, but nothing happened

```
log_level = debug_rpc_answer
```

Thanks

Comment: The log_level will be logged to Odoo's log file which is visible if you are on the server itself, i.e. not on Odoo's UI

Comment: Sorry, I want to log RPC request and response data in the log file, not log level :))